# Password con ateriscos en el panel de propiedades

Tags: c#, activity, uipath

Voy a tratar de ser claro ya que ni aunque ponga código se va a entender claramente mi pregunta.

Llevo días queriendo hacer un `activity` el cual me ponga asteriscos en el campo `password` así como se ve en la siguiente imagen y no logro resultados satisfactorios... Probé incluso haciendo un dotpeek a la dll del get password poniendo todo tal cual y me aparece con letras la password, no me aparece con asteriscos.

[image: Password]

Busqué, encontré algo, pero ningún resultado resolvió mi inconveniente. Ahora voy a cambiar mi planteo, mi idea es poder hacer una propiedad `password` en windows forms con custom controls y si logro hacerlo ahí trasladarlo a `uipath` como un `activity`.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano

Comment: He editado las etiquetas. Creo que estás usando esto no? https://www.uipath.com/

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta, en el textbox en c# del windows form, tienes una propiedad passworChar, que si le pones el * te lo cambia automaticamente

Comment: Claro, no es Windows Forms, sino UIPath en este se manejan System.Activities

Comment: Quiero que el campo enmascare la password sin poner paswordCher

Comment: ¿Has probado a manejarlo como SecureString?

Comment: Si, ya lo he intentado y no hubo caso... se trata de un custom activity el cual quiero que reciba texto enmascarado igual que get password

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor para estos casos es crear credenciales desde el orquestador en lugar de meterlas "a pelo". De esta forma ya van cifradas y simplemente creas las variables con ese nombre.

Salu2.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/345698)